# Multiple instances of same vuejs component (popover) show same data on click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eventemitter, popper.js, vue-props

I am trying to show an AJAX response in a popover displayed by an icon (a custom Vue component which I wrote) when it is clicked.
There are multiple instances of this component, which are rendered dynamically using the v-for directive in a table:

**ParentComponent.vue**

```
...
<tr v-for="(table, index) in tables" :key="index">
            <th scope="row">{{ index + 1 }}</th>
            <td scope="row">
              {{ table }}
            </td>
            <th scope="row">
              <Popover :popoverData="popoverData" @on-click="previewTable(table)" />
</tr> 
...
async previewTable(table) {
      
      const response = await axios.get(RestApi + `/${table}`);
      this.popoverData = response.data;
    }
```

**Popover.vue**

```
<template>
  <button class="btn" ref="button" aria-describedby="tooltip" @click='this.$emit("onClick")'>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
  </button>
  <div id="tooltip" ref="tooltip" role="tooltip">
    {{ popoverData }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { createPopper } from "@popperjs/core";

export default {
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  props: { popoverData: String },
  mounted: ...
```

The problem is that when I click on one of these components ( which should show a popover with text coming fron an API call) and then I click on a second one without closing the first, the data looks like shared and not uniquely assigned to that specific instance of the component. I am also attaching an image to express things in clearer way (the API response is here replaced by table name) .
[image: As an example, the API response is replaced by table name]
Thanks for the support.

Comment: You pass the exact same `popoverData` prop to each Popover

Comment: Ok, then how could I keep distinct props for each component in a dynamic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, you pass the exact same `popoverData` prop to each Popover. To fix this, you probably can store distinct values for each popover in an object, using `table` (whatever it is) as a key:

ParentComponent script

```
data() {
  return {
    popovers: {},
    ...
  }
}
...
methods: {
  async previewTable(table) {
    const response = await axios.get(RestApi + `/${table}`);
    this.$set(this.popovers, table, response.data);
  }
  ...
}
```

ParentComponent template

```
<Popover :popoverData="popovers[table]" @on-click="previewTable(table)" />
```